# Enabling interface TenGigE0/0/2/0 pls help

Tags: cisco, networking, asr

I'm trying to enable just one SFP+ port for testing a 10gbit NIC. I cannot, however, for the life of me find how to enable a port. To me, it would make sense to

1. conf t
2. interfaces TenGigE0/0/2/0 admin up ( or something like this)
   I know this isn't right, but it is where my brain is currently.

Everything I can find just says to use "no shutdown" then reload the config. Completely new to cisco stuff and I'm becoming frustrated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
troz-gw-1#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
troz-gw-1(config)#interface TenGigE0/0/2/0
troz-gw-1(config-if)#no shut
troz-gw-1(config-if)#exit
troz-gw-1(config)#exit
troz-gw-1#wr mem
```

That's what is meant by "no shut". (of course, there's a ton more configuration to make an interface fully operational -- addresses, etc.)

Comment: IOS XR will have a few more steps, depending on the context from which you start.